# Is it reflexive: everyone who has visited Web page a has also visited Web page b, for all webpages

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

This is a question from "Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications":

```
Determine whether the relation R on the set of all Web
pages is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, and/or tran-sitive, 
where(a, b) ∈ R if and only if

a) everyone who has visited Web page a has also visited Web page b .
```

The answer is:

```
a) Reflexive, transitive
```

I don't understand well why it's "Reflexive". If there is a web page which has never been visited by anybody, `(a,a)` won't be belonged to `R`, that `R` should not be reflexive, right?

Do I misunderstand something wrong?

---

Thanks for @Brian M. Scott's answer, I understand it now. Let me add something important here:

The description of $R$ is:

$R$={$(x,y) | \forall p (F(p,x) \to F(p,y))$}, where $F(p,x)$ means "p has visited x", and $ p \in P $ where P is "all people".

When page $x$ has never been visited, that $F(p,x), p \in P$ is always `false`, that $\forall p (F(p,x) \to F(p,y))$ is always `true`, that `F(x, any y)` is always `true`.

That's why the relation is "Reflexive".

Comment: It will be helpful for you to review the definition of a relation first. What does $aRb$ mean? What does $aba$ mean?

Comment: "Everyone who has visited the Sun has (also) visited the Sun" is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $a$ is a web page, let $V(a)$ be the set of people who have visited $a$. Then $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$ if and only if $V(a)\subseteq V(b)$. Now it’s always true that $V(a)\subseteq V(a)$, even if $V(a)=\varnothing$, so it’s always true that $\langle a,a\rangle\in R$. Thus, $R$ really is reflexive.

Here’s a slightly different way to look at it. If $a$ and $b$ are particular web pages, how could you prove that $\langle a,b\rangle\notin R$? You would have to find someone who has visited $a$ but has not visited $b$. If no one has visited $a$, you can’t do this: you can’t find anyone who has visited $a$, let alone someone who has visited $a$ but not $b$! This shows that if $a$ has never been visited, then $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$ for **all** $b$ (and hence certainly for the particular case $b=a$).

Comment: $R$={$(x,y) | \forall p (F(p,x)  \to F(p,y))$}, where $F(p,x)$ means "p has visited x". Is it right?

Comment: @Freewind: Yes, that’s one correct way to describe it, though it would be better if you wrote $\forall p\in P$ and defined $P$ to be the set of all people.

Comment: If page $x$ has never been visited, that $F(p,x)$ will always be `false`, that $\forall p (F(p,x) \to F(p,y))$ will be `true`, so $(x, any y)$ belong to $R$.

Comment: @Freewind: Yes, that’s right.